# How to beat Snatch & Grab?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, achievements

I'm down to my last Spec Ops mission to get Star 69: Snatch and Grab on Veteran.

I can not for the life of me beat this.  I've tried 2 player and solo. I've beaten it on easier levels.  I've even tried that crazy charging strategy which I saw on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLSZvBT73G4).  I'm kinda at my wits end here.

Any advice would be helpful... I've seriously tried over 100 times.

Comment: Hehe I didn't realise how old this question was when I answered. Oh well. So, did you beat it?

Comment: @David yeah Cmrn's advice really helped me.  The problem I got into was trying to deal with both sides after the airplane. [Only 1 achievement left](http://live.xbox.com/en-US/profile/Achievements/ViewAchievementDetails.aspx?tid=%09]:`m/l;|w&compareTo=Jim+0 "Don't ask why Jim, its a long story")

Comment: Cool. 'Downed But Not Out' isn't too hard to get in spec ops, you're almost there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the mission that I found hardest too.

My buddy and I finally beat it by playing through cautiously until the intel, clearing as far ahead without jumping down with the sniper rifles, then grabbing the intel and pretty much sprinting down the left side for the exit. I shot people that were dead infront of me if I was out of sprint, but otherwise just run and revive your buddy. Make sure your friend takes a slightly different path than you, so you cant both get mowed down by the same enemy.

Keep at it, it's length and difficulty make it one of the hardest *Spec Ops* missions.

Answer (score 1):

The first few yard areas can be tricky but if you are patient and don't open yourself up to too many enemies at once (ie. don't move around too fast) you can get past them fairly consistently.

The real crux of this mission is the plane where you drop down before the escape. Take out the guys in the "valley" area below the split plane; and as didi said, kill the juggernauts that come up behind you (this can be hard). Once down I got on top of the downed plane that is just to your left. From there you can shoot down on guys you couldn't see before. To beat the juggernauts on the ground in the valley you can run up onto the plane wing and get some shots off then jump off one of the sides to give yourself a breather before you run up and go for him again. Basically keep running up the wing and getting shots off when you can. Just don't let them get close to you.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

Snatch & Grab is easy ... save for the juggernauts. Make sure you have a buddy, and one of you should have a sniper rifle as secondary. Headshot him 3 times when he's far away and Bob's your uncle. 
Also, before "jumping out" of the plane, after grabbing the intel, be sure your buddy is watching your ass while you're clearing the area below. JUggernauts ALWAYS show up from the back, just before you jump off the plane. So, you'll jump off, a bunch will spawn in front, a juggernaut in front, and on top of that, a juggernaut from the back. Don't jump off until the back juggernaut is dead.